# DB Connection Pool from Stand Alone Java program

Tags: java, jms, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am running a Stand Alone Java JMS client subsriber. I need to Connect to MS-SQL DB to put the messages. Traffic is more so need to use Connection Pool.

I have got some samples link [https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/313173]

I had spent a lot of time in above samples, but at last came to know that these are stick to application server.

Now for Stand alone how to get Connection Pool for MS-SQL DB??

Please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the standalone connection pooling you can use third party libraries like  Apache DBCP or spring ..

Comment: Try to support your answer with some code, if you want to suggest something, try commenting instead.

Comment: @shiju , Does Apache DBCP  support for MS-SQL DB as well?

Comment: Yes.  Please find the below example                                BasicDataSource source = new BasicDataSource();
            source.setDriverClassName(className);
            source.setUsername(username);
            source.setPassword(password);
            source.setUrl(url);

Comment: @ FaizanRabbani. Can you please say how to use apache connection pooling in infinite loop. Every loop process a request.